# How to Find the generic type of a class and cast a value to that type?

Tags: java

In a third-party code there is the following function:

```
public <F extends OFValueType<F>> Builder setExact(MatchField<F> field, F value) throws UnsupportedOperationException;
```

Now, given a   `MatchField<F> field` variable, how can I find the type "F" of that variable. So that, I can cast a given value to type "F" and send the casted value to the function setExact();

Comment: You can't. That's all erased.

Comment: Are you aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929527/how-to-find-the-class-object-of-java-generic-type and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004022/java-generic-class-determine-type ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just cast to `OFValueType` in your case?